# Issues Generating .edmx EF6 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am trying to generate my edmx file for my database in Visual Studio 2013 against either a mssql 2012 or 2008 database server and table set. The edmx file generates with out issue, and everything looks fine until i try to compile the project. Every single object representing a database table errors out with the following messages.

1. A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System' is a type not a namespace
2. The type name 'Collections' does not exist in the type 'Model.blah.System'
3. The type name 'DateTime' does not exist in the type 'Model.blah.System'

The using statements are correctly located inside the generated codes name space declaration, just like all other EF .edmx files i have seen in the past.

The error messages are consistent across the board for all database objects. NO matter what i do how i generate the my edmx model it is useless and not usable.

I am running with Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. I have tried using EF5 and EF6 to no avail. I need some help figuring out why for the life of me i can't correctly generate my EF model.

Answer (score 8):

I'd guess that you have a namespace collision, where the compiler fails because you defined a `System` class that is ambiguous with the `System` namespace.

Rename your `System` class to something else to solve your problem.

Comment: When the problem first appeared I went about editing the pretty much all the generated code files to move the usings outside of namespace. But i shouldn't have to. Either this is a problem with the latest visual studio editor or the 4.51 .net framework. I thought it might be a namespace collision too as you are suggesting, so i created a standalone new project with nothing in it, but the EF generated code and it still doesn't compile.

Comment: Do you have *anything* with **System** in the name?  A database, database table, property name, etc?

Comment: Yup, have a table named "System" in my model. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Found the issue I had a Systems table that would stand for systems of measurement. When EF would process the tables it would remove the s from the end of the table causing a name conflict to occur. I am going to close this question, but wanted to get this out there for people to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you, saved me from hours of frustration