# Entity Framework from Database Generate Namespace Errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, namespaces

I'm generating a EF Model from database and I get using namespace errors from the auto generated code on all of the classes generated by EF.

Here is an example of one of the classes:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WebApplication5.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Flag
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int UserGameID { get; set; }

    public virtual UserGame UserGame { get; set; }
}
}
```

I get the following error on builing:

A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System' is a type not a namespace

Comment: I there a generated class `System`?

Comment: Thx arnold i didn't even realize that was the problem

Comment: I have same error and when put  using System; using System.Collections.Generic; out side of namespace my error has solved :O

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Sorry I wasn't clear about the problem. I had the exact problem [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25923074/issues-generating-edmx-ef6-in-visual-studio-2013) but didn't realize my table was causing the problem.